# Android+Phonegap::Ajax "loading" GIF does not animate

Tags: android, cordova

Hi i am developing android phonegap application and i am using GIF image for showing loading indication.

```
 <div id="LoadingImage">
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loader" alt="loader image"/>
        </div>
```

but it is working properly in android above 3.2 version but its not working in android 2.3 version.Can any one help me to make it works.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://getsatisfaction.com/tiggzi/topics/ajax_loader_gif_freezes) and then tell if it worked out for you.
If this page doesn't exist :) try [this one here](https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio/topics/default_ajax_spinner_freezes).

Answer (score 0):

In android manifest file please set

```
min SDK version="8" and check it out.
```